# How to apply RotateAnimation on ImageView inside a widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to play a refresh button rotate animation inside my widget on button click. I tried to do:

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, 15f, 15f);
anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setDuration(700);

// Start animating the image
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
ImageView image = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null).findViewById(R.id.refreshBtnImageView);
image.startAnimation(anim);
```

But it does not work. My refresh button is inside a widget and i am listening for the button click in BroadcastReceiver. Can I reference ImageView like this in BroadcastReceiver or do i need to use RemoteViews for that? If RemoteViews, then how can I apply animation on that?

Thanks!